# Javascript to hide every element in div if it's height is 0

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I'm looking for a way to hide every element (set to display:none) in a div (marked with a class or an id) if the height of the element is 0.

Example. Hide elem1 and elem4

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="elem1" style="height:0"> ... </ul>
    <ul id="elem2" style="height:50"> ... </ul>
    <ul id="elem3" style="height:40"> ... </ul>
    <ul id="elem4" style="height:0"> ... </ul>
    <ul id="elem5" style="height:60"> ... </ul>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: Please read the FAQ. You're expected to show you've at least tried.

Comment: If its height is 0, surely it's not going to be displaying much anyway? Maybe some borders I guess...

Answer (score 3):

Try this one for size:

```
.container ul[style="height:0"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/yBJEe/

---

The following will work no matter if there is a space after the `:` or not:

```
.container ul[style~="0"], .container ul[style="height:0"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/yBJEe/3/

Comment: Kicked the crap out of my answer. +1

Comment: That's pretty cool, now add a space to the style -> http://jsfiddle.net/yBJEe/2/ and see what happens

Comment: Yeah, adaneo is right. "height:<space>0" changes this. <ul id="elem1" style="height: 0"> will crash that.

Comment: @adeneo The CSS is checking on that **exact** string. So anything different would yield a different result.

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS sample. Mark your elements with a class. This will work:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class='yourClass' id="elem1" style="height:0">.1..</ul>
    <ul class='yourClass' id="elem2" style="height:50">.2..</ul>
    <ul class='yourClass' id="elem3" style="height:40">.3..</ul>
    <ul class='yourClass' id="elem4" style="height:0">.4..</ul>
    <ul class='yourClass' id="elem5" style="height:60">.5..</ul>
</div>
```

JS script:

```
(function hideElements() {

var the_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');
for (var i = 0; i < the_elements.length; ++i) {
    var item = the_elements[i];

    if (item.style.height === '0px') {
        item.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
})();
```

Note that the value retrieved is '0px'.
JSFiddle working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/amontellano/EgHLt/5/

Answer (score 1):

This CSS block would help

```
.container ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, using `querySelectorAll()`

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("ul[id*='elem']"); //select all elements with an ID containing 'elem'
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) { //loop the element array and check if height == 0
    if (x[i].style.height == 0) x[i].style.display = "none"; //set display to none
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use x[i].style.height === '0px'